# android UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, unsupportedoperation

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception in dex writer thread
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':wofangMgr:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This may be some process ocuppied the dex file . Try to restart android stuido or clean your project.

Comment: this should be comment

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that usually goes away if you restart Android Studio

Comment: this should be comment

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your test device Android API version,such as android 7.0.
Some library don't support the android api that is too old.